# How to implement radio button inside a drop down component in React Native

Tags: react-native, drop-down-menu, radio-button

I want to implement a drop down component in react native in which one of the item in the drop down list can be selected using a radio button component in react native.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-radio-button

```
mport RadioForm, {RadioButton, RadioButtonInput, RadioButtonLabel} from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';


var radio_props = [
  {label: 'param1', value: 0 },
  {label: 'param2', value: 1 }
];

<RadioForm
  radio_props={radio_props}
  initial={0}
  onPress={(value) => {this.setState({value:value})}}
/>
```